# How to get only the module name ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-module

How only to print the module name with ModuleNotFoundError arguments in Python.

My code:

```
try:
    import requests
except ModuleNotFoundError as error1:
    print(error1)
```

In this case I am getting output as below:

```
>> No module named *'requests'*
```

I want to be printed only the *name of the module* that met the exception.

Output I need:

```
>> 'requests'
```

Comment: Either hardcore, or perhaps use string manipulation to extract the 'requests' from the string?

Comment: @Frontear could you please mention the code, thanks

Comment: is there anything like print(error1.__modulename__)

Comment: i posted some code below, check it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module name in an `ModuleNotFoundError` is accessed by the variable `name`

```
try:
    import this_module_doesnt_exist
except ModuleNotFoundError as error1:
    print(error1.name)
```

Output:

```
this_module_doesnt_exist
```

Comment: learn something new everyday

Comment: @Frontear I found it out by assigning the error to a variable `tmp` and then doing `help(tmp)` the docstring said the variable to use :)

Comment: @MSH I could do it myself, but I knew that the variable would be held by the class. Hence why I tried to find out what variable was being used.

Comment: you can also call `dir()` to find the methods/properties an object (such as `error1` in the except scope this case!)

Comment: Very well done. You just reminded us we can always get `help` for any returned value. :)

Comment: @ti7 Nice, I didnt know you could do that. I was trying to use `__dict__` but it didn't return anything

Comment: @TomMcLean MSH is likely referring to the `help()` command, which dumps "a help page on the object" and much more and is often similarly used for discovery as `dir()` can be! https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the string to extract the module name. You can see the module name is between two single quotes. Knowing this, we can use str.index to find the two indexes, and extract all data between them to get the module name.

```py
try:
    import blahblahdoesntexist
except ModuleNotFoundError as err1:
    error = str(err1) # turns it into a string
    first = error.index("'")
    last = error.index("'", first + 1)

    print(error[first + 1:last]) # gets the name only.
```

Comment: thanks @Frontear

Answer (score -1):

As you already know the name of the module you're trying to import, you could just write it directly

```py
try:
    import requests
except ImportError as ex:
    sys.exit(f"unable to import requests: {repr(ex)} .. you can install it with 'pip install requests')
```

However, watch out, this could be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) of some form!

ie. why is requests not installed? (maybe you should bundle a `pip_requirements.txt` file or create a `setup.py`)
[Packaging Python Projects Docs](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/)

Comment: try:
    import requests
    import os
    import fileinput
except ModuleNotFoundError as err:
    print(err)
    
    no , i dont want to do that , i have to import more modules

Comment: ti7 has a valid response. If youre gonna check this sort of thing, you may as well bundle a requirements file. Why is this the way youre choosing to go about it?

Comment: the new python 3.10 doesnot contain request module at fresh

Comment: I think this is not valid since the question is `how to get only the module name ModuleNotFoundError`. Other operations are irrelevant. We don't know why this question was asked. Maybe it's just out of curiosity .

Comment: @vishnus `requests` is a very common, but still a 3rd party module and has never been included in Python (though I believe it builds partially on `urllib`, which is!) https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/ https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request